# Set JENKINS_HOME in Tomcat7?

Tags: jenkins, tomcat7

I'm trying to set up Jenkins in Tomcat7 on Ubuntu.  I installed Tomcat7 and deployed `jenkins.war`, and I now see the Jenkins home page at `http://myhost:8080/jenkins`, but it's attempting to create the Jenkins directory at `/usr/share/tomcat7/.jenkins`, which it can't for security reasons.  I've already created `/srv/jenkins` and given the `tomcat7` group permissions, and want to set `JENKINS_HOME` to that path.  I've tried adding it to the tomcat configuration in `/etc/tomcat7/server.xml`:

```
<GlobalNamingResources>

  <Environment name="JENKINS_HOME" value="/srv/jenkins"
       type="java.lang.String" override="false"/>
  <!-- Default settings -->
```

And I've also tried adding it to the automatically created context file in `ROOT/META-INF/context.xml` (there is no `$CATALINA_HOME/conf` as far as I can tell).

```
<Context path="/"
        antiResourceLocking="false" >
    <Environment name="JENKINS_HOME" value="/srv/jenkins/" type="java.lang.String"/>
</Context>
```

But even after restarting tomcat7 I still get the same result (trying to use `/usr/share/tomcat7/.jenkins`).

Where do I need to set the environment variable for `JENKINS_HOME` in Tomcat7?

Answer (score 3):

It isn't exactly the solution I prefer, but I created the `/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/setenv.sh` script as described in `catalina.sh`.

```
#!
export JENKINS_HOME=/srv/jenkins
```

And of course gave it execute permissions with `chmod ugo+x setenv.sh`.

Answer (score 3):

I set it in `/etc/default/tomcat7`.  For your example, append this line:

```
JENKINS_HOME=/srv/jenkins
```

Answer (score 1):

A symbolic link approach where my jenkins-data go to a backed-up filesystem.

```
[root@lx08 tomcat6]# ln -s /data01/jenkins .jenkins
[root@lx08 tomcat6]# ls -la
total 12
drwxrwxr-x    3 root root   4096 Dec 27 13:00 .
drwxr-xr-x. 181 root root   4096 Dec 27 11:28 ..
drwxr-xr-x    2 root root   4096 Dec 27 11:28 bin
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root tomcat   12 Dec 27 11:28 conf -> /etc/tomcat6
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root root     15 Dec 27 13:00 .jenkins -> /data01/jenkins
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root root     23 Dec 27 11:28 lib -> /usr/share/java/tomcat6
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root root     16 Dec 27 11:28 logs -> /var/log/tomcat6
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root root     23 Dec 27 11:28 temp -> /var/cache/tomcat6/temp
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root root     24 Dec 27 11:28 webapps -> /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root root     23 Dec 27 11:28 work -> /var/cache/tomcat6/work
[root@lx08 tomcat6]# pwd
/usr/share/tomcat6

[root@lx08 tomcat6]# export JENKINS_HOME=http://localhost:8080/jenkins
[root@lx08 tomcat6]# java -jar /usr/share/tomcat6/webapps/jenkins/WEB-INF/lib/jenkins-core-1.495.jar  "TestJob" echo hello
hello
```

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way is to edit the context descriptor of the Tomcat servlet ($CATALINA_HOME/conf/config.xml) and add the folowing line:

```
<Context ...>
  <Environment name="JENKINS_HOME" value="/path/to/jenkins_home/" type="java.lang.String"/>
</Context>
```

Viewed in https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Tomcat

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation I've read and a couple examples above, Jenkins uses your Tomcat user's home directory and searches for a .jenkins in that folder. Make sure your Tomcat user's home directory is set to a value you expect, /opt/apache/tomcat for example, and create a .jenkins symlink in that folder pointing to where your Jenkins folder lives.

```
ln -s /path/to/jenkins_home /opt/apache/tomcat/.jenkins
```